# Mbean calls are failing with empty credentials in WAS 855 when security is ON

Tags: java, websphere

I am getting the below error when security is enabled in websphere 8.5.5 for MBean calls.
I see this issue only on few systems wherever we are starting application server after switch user using command SUDO SU - ROOT

2016-08-11 04:06:23,786 [WebContainer : 6] INFO  ejb3.PersistentObjectDAOBean in abc.xyz

retrieved object for: abc.x.persist.WorkflowInstancePersist with id: 302051223; lastModifyDate: 2016-08-10T04:18:03.294-0400

2016-08-11 04:06:23,796 [WebContainer : 6] INFO  xyz.NcrJndiTemplate in abc.xyz

provider url: corbaloc:iiop:localhost:9810

2016-08-11 04:06:24,135 [WebContainer : 6] WARN  impl.WorkflowWebService in abc.xyz

Web service [String com.abc.impl.WorkflowWebService.getWorkflowInstanceDetail(long)] is throwing exception which may or may not be expected by client. Arguments: [302051223 ; ].

javax.ejb.EJBException: See nested exception; nested exception is: javax.management.JMRuntimeException:

```
   >> SERVER (id=4773e3aa, host=WAS01) TRACE START:

   >>    javax.management.JMRuntimeException: ADMN0022E: Access is denied for the getActiveLogs operation on ProcessManagerServiceMBean MBean because of insufficient or empty credentials.

   >>     at com.ibm.ws.management.AdminServiceImpl.preInvoke(AdminServiceImpl.java:2509)

   >>     at com.ibm.ws.management.AdminServiceImpl$1.run(AdminServiceImpl.java:1327)

   >>     at com.ibm.ws.security.util.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:118)

   >>     at com.ibm.ws.management.AdminServiceImpl.invoke(AdminServiceImpl.java:1243)

   >>     at com.ibm.ws.management.remote.AdminServiceForwarder.invoke(AdminServiceForwarder.java:346)

   >>     at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1503)

   >>     at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.access$300(RMIConnectionImpl.java:109)

   >>     at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1344)

   >>     at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1436)

   >>     at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(RMIConnectionImpl.java:864)

   >>     at javax.management.remote.rmi._RMIConnectionImpl_Tie.invoke(Unknown Source)

   >>     at javax.management.remote.rmi._RMIConnectionImpl_Tie._invoke(Unknown Source)

   >>     at com.ibm.CORBA.iiop.ServerDelegate.dispatchInvokeHandler(ServerDelegate.java:628)

   >>     at com.ibm.CORBA.iiop.ServerDelegate.dispatch(ServerDelegate.java:510)

   >>     at com.ibm.rmi.iiop.ORB.process(ORB.java:606)

   >>     at com.ibm.CORBA.iiop.ORB.process(ORB.java:1583)

   >>     at com.ibm.rmi.iiop.Connection.doRequestWork(Connection.java:3166)

   >>     at com.ibm.rmi.iiop.Connection.doWork(Connection.java:3030)

   >>     at com.ibm.rmi.iiop.WorkUnitImpl.doWork(WorkUnitImpl.java:64)

   >>     at com.ibm.ws.giop.threadpool.WorkQueueElement.dispatch(WorkQueueElement.java:174)

   >>     at com.ibm.ws.giop.filter.GiopFilterChain.processMessage(GiopFilterChain.java:203)

   >>     at com.ibm.ws.giop.threadpool.PooledThread.handleRequest(PooledThread.java:81)

   >>     at com.ibm.ws.giop.threadpool.PooledThread.run(PooledThread.java:102)

   >>     at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1881)

   >> SERVER (id=4773e3aa, host=WAS01) TRACE END.



   at com.ibm.ejs.container.util.ExceptionUtil.EJBException(ExceptionUtil.java:475)

   at com.ibm.ejs.container.util.ExceptionUtil.EJBException(ExceptionUtil.java:365)

   at com.ibm.ejs.container.BusinessExceptionMappingStrategy.mapException(BusinessExceptionMappingStrategy.java:392)

   at com.ibm.ejs.container.BusinessExceptionMappingStrategy.setUncheckedException(BusinessExceptionMappingStrategy.java:554)

   at com.ibm.ejs.container.EJSDeployedSupport.setUncheckedLocalException(EJSDeployedSupport.java:567)


   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)

   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:95)

   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:56)

   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:620)

   at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.performInvocation(AbstractInvoker.java:180)

   at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.invoke(AbstractInvoker.java:96)

   at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.AbstractJAXWSMethodInvoker.invoke(AbstractJAXWSMethodInvoker.java:178)

   at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JAXWSMethodInvoker.invoke(JAXWSMethodInvoker.java:67)

   at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.invoke(AbstractInvoker.java:75)

   at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor$1.run(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:57)

   at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:483)

   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:274)

   at org.apache.cxf.workqueue.SynchronousExecutor.execute(SynchronousExecutor.java:37)

   at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor.handleMessage(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:106)

   at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:263)

   at org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:121)

   at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination.invoke(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:240)

   at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invokeDestination(ServletController.java:239)

   at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:213)

   at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFNonSpringServlet.invoke(CXFNonSpringServlet.java:131)

   at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.handleRequest(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:266)

   at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.doPost(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:186)

   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:595)

   at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.service(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:242)

   at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1232)

   at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:781)

   at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:480)

   at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:178)

   at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.invokeTarget(WebAppFilterChain.java:136)

   at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:97)

   at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)

   at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)

   at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)

   at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)

   at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)

   at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)

   at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)

   at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)

   at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)

   at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)

   at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.java:139)

   at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)

   at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:154)

   at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)

   at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)

   at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)

   at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:150)

   at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)

   at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ui.DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter.doFilter(DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter.java:155)

   at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)

   at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:199)

   at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)

   at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:110)

   at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)

   at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:50)

   at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)

   at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)

   at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)

   at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)

   at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)

   at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)

   at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:344)

   at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:261)

   at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:195)

   at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91)

   at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:967)

   at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1107)

   at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.CacheServletWrapper.handleRequest(CacheServletWrapper.java:87)

   at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:940)

   at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1817)

   at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:200)

   at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:463)

   at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:530)

   at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:316)

   at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.ready(HttpInboundLink.java:287)

   at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.sendToDiscriminators(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:214)

   at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.complete(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:113)

   at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:175)

   at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)

   at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture$1.run(AsyncChannelFuture.java:205)

   at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1881)
```

Caused by: javax.management.JMRuntimeException:

```
   >> SERVER (id=4773e3aa, host=WAS01) TRACE START:

   >>    javax.management.JMRuntimeException: ADMN0022E: Access is denied for the getActiveLogs operation on ProcessManagerServiceMBean MBean because of insufficient or empty credentials.

   >>     at com.ibm.ws.management.AdminServiceImpl.preInvoke(AdminServiceImpl.java:2509)

   >>     at com.ibm.ws.management.AdminServiceImpl$1.run(AdminServiceImpl.java:1327)

   >>     at com.ibm.ws.security.util.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:118)

   >>     at com.ibm.ws.management.AdminServiceImpl.invoke(AdminServiceImpl.java:1243)

   >>     at com.ibm.ws.management.remote.AdminServiceForwarder.invoke(AdminServiceForwarder.java:346)

   >>     at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1503)

   >>     at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.access$300(RMIConnectionImpl.java:109)

   >>     at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1344)

   >>     at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1436)

   >>     at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(RMIConnectionImpl.java:864)

   >>     at javax.management.remote.rmi._RMIConnectionImpl_Tie.invoke(Unknown Source)

   >>     at javax.management.remote.rmi._RMIConnectionImpl_Tie._invoke(Unknown Source)

   >>     at com.ibm.CORBA.iiop.ServerDelegate.dispatchInvokeHandler(ServerDelegate.java:628)

   >>     at com.ibm.CORBA.iiop.ServerDelegate.dispatch(ServerDelegate.java:510)

   >>     at com.ibm.rmi.iiop.ORB.process(ORB.java:606)

   >>     at com.ibm.CORBA.iiop.ORB.process(ORB.java:1583)

   >>     at com.ibm.rmi.iiop.Connection.doRequestWork(Connection.java:3166)

   >>     at com.ibm.rmi.iiop.Connection.doWork(Connection.java:3030)

   >>     at com.ibm.rmi.iiop.WorkUnitImpl.doWork(WorkUnitImpl.java:64)

   >>     at com.ibm.ws.giop.threadpool.WorkQueueElement.dispatch(WorkQueueElement.java:174)

   >>     at com.ibm.ws.giop.filter.GiopFilterChain.processMessage(GiopFilterChain.java:203)

   >>     at com.ibm.ws.giop.threadpool.PooledThread.handleRequest(PooledThread.java:81)

   >>     at com.ibm.ws.giop.threadpool.PooledThread.run(PooledThread.java:102)

   >>     at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1881)

   >> SERVER (id=4773e3aa, host=WAS01) TRACE END.
```

Comment: Any application code that has been written for extracting data from JMX  or is it something Out of the box ?

Comment: yes, the code has written to extract environment variables from websphere AdminServiceFactory MBean was failing with above error. I have resolved with below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Configuring below JVM Arguments resolved the issue -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,addres‌​s=7778 Generic JVM Arguments: -Xjit:disableLocalVP,disableGlobalVP -Djavax.management.builder.initial= -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote 
similar resolution discussed in below site stackoverflow.com/questions/357095/…